How can I effectively trace code paths for fuzz testing in a Bitcoin core?
I want to write a fuzz test to increase the coverage of net_processing.cpp for this piece of code. But I am unable to navigate/trace from where this function is being called .
I have checked in net_tests.cpp and transaction_tests.cpp in whose piece of code RelayTransaction function was used but its not being used in tests .This would mean its being called inside tests internally . This picture is from the total_coverage generated from lcov .

How should i go about writing the test ?

It seems you are asking for an explanation of the code? And actually of a good chunk of the relay logic.

@AntoinePoinsot My wording might not have been clear for this question . I want to ask about how should one go about navigating to specific lines when fuzzing . Ideally some fuzzers or compilers would give the trace of the execution when calling functions so it is easy to navigate what was called and so. However I dont know if such thing is possible while writing tests for bitcoin-core. I wanted to ask how developers would write tests when in these scenarios ?

This chunk of code comes from one of the PR I am reviewing and I wanted to code test for this to increase coverage . I just cant figure out where this function is being hit .

I’m voting to close this question because i don't think it's appropriate for this site to explain the Bitcoin Core codebase (outside of maybe very specific snippets but it's clearly not the case here).

@AntoinePoinsot: It seems to me that asking about Bitcoin Core’s behavior would be on-topic. However, the confusion here might be stemming from the section of code being inactive in that PR and therefore not triggering because it’s part of an unfinished feature.

I agree. What i meant is that we can't explain how the C++ codebase work, unless it's very specific snippets of code.
